# How can I get rid of the line in pylab histogram

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I have this simplified code:

```
import numpy, pylab, random

data = [ random.gauss(1, 0.2) for x in range(1000) ]

fig = pylab.figure()
weights = numpy.ones_like(data)/float(len(data))
n, bins, patches =pylab.hist(data, bins=20, histtype='stepfilled', 
                             weights=weights)
pylab.xlim(min(bins), max(bins))
pylab.ylim(0, 1)
p, = pylab.plot(bins)
pylab.savefig("test.png")
```

And the plot looks like this:

[image: test.png]

What is that green line? How can I remove it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because you are plotting the bins points of x-axis on the y-axis (that's the green line), you don't need the `plot()`:

```
import numpy, pylab, random

data = [ random.gauss(1, 0.2) for x in range(1000) ]

fig = pylab.figure()
weights = numpy.ones_like(data)/float(len(data))
n, bins, patches =pylab.hist(data, bins=20, histtype='bar', 
                         weights=weights)
pylab.xlim(min(bins), max(bins))
pylab.ylim(0, 1)
pylab.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I've been trying to get rid of it for days :)

Comment: The green line are the bins points of x-axis, you were plotting them on y-axis